# Which Drupal Version Is Best

Tags: 7

I have a new site that I'm starting to build but I need help deciding what makes Drupal 7 better than Drupal 6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should answer your question well enough: [Choosing a Drupal version](http://drupal.org/documentation/version-info)

> In deciding between Drupal 6 and Drupal 7, several factors should be
>   taken into consideration. Drupal 7 is newer, will be supported longer,
>   and contains more features and enhancements than Drupal 6; therefore,
>   if all else is equal, use Drupal 7. However, the releases of
>   contributed modules, themes, translations, and installation profiles
>   compatible with each major Drupal release series sometimes lag behind
>   Drupal itself, so if the functionality you need is not yet available
>   for Drupal 7, this may affect your decision.

Drupal 6 is getting closer and closer to being completely unsupported (there are only two supported versions at any one time, and Drupal 8 *should* be out within 12 months - so 6 will become unsupported), and there are very few modules being made available for it.

Personally, I don't know of anybody who would want to start building a website/application in Drupal 6 over Drupal 7.

***tl;dr***

Everything makes D7 better than D6

Comment: Thank you very much. Thank sure put me on the right track to start.